# Enable mousewheel on TIsDBLookupComboBox drop down list in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, combobox

I am using Delphi 7. I have a TIsDBLookupComboBox, a database combobox from IS Data Controls component tab.

It works fine, it populates its list from a database... but the trouble is mouse wheel. Mouse wheel scrolling isnt working on the drop down list... How can I enable it? 
I know it is an old version of Delphi... but I must stick to it.

Thank you very much..

Comment: I'm guessing, but maybe the reason you haven't got any responses is because nobody knows what a TIsDBLookupComboBox is.  Googling it only finds references to this question.  Googling 'Delphi "IS Data Controls"' doesn't seem to find anything useful either.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Well how do I name it then?

Comment: How do you name what, exactly?  Are you actually talking about the standard TDBLookupComboBox which comes with Delphi or what?

Comment: Please take a look at this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/8vvgyt

Comment: Well, you must know where you got them from, so ask the author.

Comment: ok, thanks for your time.